# Get all user profiles from list of users

Tags: rules, users

I am evaluating some custom code in a rule. I want to get a list of users, then load all of the associated profiles from the profile2 module. My code below, loads all the users, and I got an array of the UIDs to put into the profile_load_multiple() function but it is just returning one user profile, I want to return all profiles. Eventually I want to compare a term from a field (project resources) in the node 'project' I am creating with a field (resources) that is in each user main profile.  My intention is  using rules to accomplish this.

```
$users = entity_load('user');
$arrayuids = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
array_push($arrayuids, $user->uid);
}
$profile = profile2_load_multiple($arrayuids, FALSE);
dsm($arrayuids);
dsm($profile);
```

Comment: Consider using Views Bulk operations module + Rules for jobs like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you send uids instead of pids. First argument of profile2_load_multiple is $pids which are profile2 ids.

Try this code:

```
$users = entity_load('user');
$arrayuids = array_keys($users);

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();    
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')
    ->propertyCondition('uid', $arrayuids, 'IN');

$profile = $query->execute();

dsm($arrayuids);
dsm($profile);
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Hi, how would I iterate through the output of $profile? It is  ... (Array, 1 element)

    profile2 (Array, 3 elements)
        1 (Object) stdClass
        2 (Object) stdClass
        3 (Object) stdClass

Comment: I am trying to get the contents with foreach($profile as $obj => $value){
dpm($value->pid);
} but this gives an error

Comment: foreach($profile as $obj){
     
     foreach($obj as $objinner)
     {
     dpm($objinner->pid);
     }

}

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on how to use EntityFieldQuery http://drupal.org/node/1343708